# How to install SourceGuardian Software

Tags: 12.04, php

[image]

I have this file (SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install) on my system, How do I install it in ubuntu 12.04lts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to use a graphical interface then:

- bring up the properties window for the file
- head over to the permissions tab
- enable **Allow executing file as program**
- Next time you double click the program you should have the choice to run it.

**Edit**

 You're using an x86_64 package on a 32-bit machine, so it obviously won't work.

Re-download the SourceGaurdian software as a **.i386** or **.i686** and it should run fine, making sure to make it executable first.

Comment: enable Allow executing file as program is already selected, and when I open the file nothing happens.

Comment: What is your PC setup?

Comment: Are you using an x86 CPU?

Comment: this is what i am running: Linux Mayowa 3.2.0-72-generic-pae #107-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 6 14:44:10 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Okay, I've re-edited the answer - hope it helps :)

Comment: It works after downloading the 32-bit  of the software. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x ./SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install
./SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install
```

Comment: oluwamayowa@Mayowa:~$ cd ~/Downloads
oluwamayowa@Mayowa:~/Downloads$ chmod +x ./SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install
oluwamayowa@Mayowa:~/Downloads$ ./SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install
bash: ./SourceGuardian-10-Evaluation-Linux-x86_64-Install: cannot execute binary file